# Trying to extend SerializeObject method of Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json.net

I am try to extend `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to make returned JSON always formatted but I am getting an error "cannot declare variable of static type `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`". I don't know what is wrong with the code, is it because I cannot extend static class JsonConvert? maybe my approach is fundamentally wrong because extension method would not override instance method. I am not sure.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public static class MakeSerializationPrettyAlways
    {
        public static string SerializeObject(this JsonConvert jc, object value)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonConvert is a static class. You can't create an extension method using a static class as the target.

The following should change your default serialization:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```